# How to redirect to an "about:" URL

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I want to be able to redirect from my website to about:version. However, about: URLs aren't valid for redirecting. Is there any way around this?
Here is some sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">See your version!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("about:version")
}
</script>
<a href = "about:version">Links dont work either</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I know - it is blocked for security reasons.

Comment: I was wondering if you can escape the colons somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">See your version!
    </button>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        const button = document.querySelector(".button");
        const redirectUrl = document.querySelector(".redirecting");
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          location.replace(redirectUrl.attributes.href.value);
        })
      }
    </script>
    <a class="redirecting" href = "about:version">Links dont work either
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code does not seem to work for me. It just redirects to "about:blank#blocked". I'm relatively sure this is for security reasons.

Comment: @yessir it probably is.